# Does Crystal Report Viewer need to be installed to view reports?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I'm re-installing an application on a users machine that uses Crystal Report after they had their machine refreshed.

After reinstalling the application it works fine.  Only when trying to run the reports does the error occur.

"Run-time error '-2147206249 (80043ae3)';invalid TLV record."

I've looked into this error but cannot find a solution.  I've noticed that they don't have a directory for Crystal Reports under the common files directory.  But the dll's are in the system32 directory.

My question is, does the Crystal Report Viewer need to be installed before the reports will run? 
ie. a directory under common files with the dll's there.

Comment: The crystal report viewer is a standalone application. If you app is loading the report and displaying it, you will need to install the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime, plus any special dlls that may be used.

Comment: When I go to the References option in the IDE for the app, it uses Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer Run Time Library 10.0, and Crystal ActiveX Report Viewer Library 10.0.  Although I can't find these version anywhere.  I used a newer one but this did not help.  Any suggestions? @jac

Comment: I would guess the distribution package is somewhere, but I know how tracking something like that down on a network can be. This is a link to SAP's web site with some information on distribution packages. It may help you. http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+Report+Designer+Component+Runtime+Distribution+-+Versions+pre+8.0.x+to+12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've built Crystal into the application then no, you should not need to.
However there are Crystal dll's, the main of which is crw32.dll, which need to
be installed on the target machine.

When you package your app it should include (and you should tick any prompts that
indicate this) packaging up the third party (such as Crystal) install files, such
as dll's. These then get installed when you install the main application.